# How to get the first line of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am wanting to get the first line of a (text)file in python. When I looked this up I got the answer of:

```
def getfirstline():
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
    return first_line
```

However when ever I execute this code I get my firstline... and a new line, so if I do:

```
newline = getfirstline()+"this goes after"
```

the "this goes after" part goes on the next line. So how can I get this to have 'this goes after' on the same line? I am in Python 3.5.

Comment: A shorter way of getting a first line would be `next(open('file.txt', 'r')).rstrip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `readline()` is called, it has a newline character at the end. Use:

```
newline = getfirstline().strip('\n') + "this goes after"
```

to strip the `\n` character before adding the other line.

Comment: Or even `rstrip` (although we know by construction there won't be any at the front!)